# Integrate CRM 2011 on premises with mailChimp

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, integration, mailchimp

I [hvae a link](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/gettingstarted/connectivity.php)
from I have MailChimp API. But I am stuck How to use this api to integrate mailchimp with crm 2011 on premises. PLease help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1.I Make custom work flow using the above code.
2.Register it in crm with the help registration tool
3.Use IlMerge to merge all Dlls
4.Make work flow in crm add my custom work flow in step
5.Follow this blog to write JS on button to trigger custom workflow
www.mscrmconsultant.com/.../execute-workflow-using-javascript-in.html

Thank You